# Error installing Laravel: [ErrorException] file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed

Tags: laravel

This is the error:

> Generating optimized autoload files
>
> ...
> [ErrorException]
> file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [] [] [<version
> ...

Comment: I tried every thing help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please review your question Title and description more clear. Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a cache problem with composer. Either you have a slow connection (like me) or a process was interrupted during install/update.

Run `composer clear-cache` and try again. I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which PHP version are you using? cause this was a bug in PHP 7.4 as stated here :
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79166

Try using PHP 7.3, it should work fine